# Photoshop generate: Possible to generate larger than document size?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, generate-image-assets

I have files where some of the graphics are larger than the document. Is it possible to use "generate" for a layer where some content is outside of the document view? (so I'll have a png/jpg that is larger than the document itself?) I presume 'no', but thought I might give it a shot here.

Answer (score 2):

**No.**

From Adobe's Help Docs on this topic:

> Assets are clipped to the document boundaries. If an image does not fall within the document boundaries, Generator does not create the associated image assets.

I think that ties that one up with a  bow.